# Desilylation Mechanism

Tags: organic-chemistry

I want to understand the mechanism of desilylation of trimethylsilyl under fluoride conditions in methanol, because I can't find any useful info that makes me understand the mechanism that takes place.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/47698/relative-basicity-of-fluorine-and-oxygen-in-silyl-ether-deprotection

Comment: It does help a lot, but my case is a little bit different because a terminal alkyne is bonded to the silyl group instead of oxygen. Why would that bond be broken and not any other carbon bond?

Comment: Think about the exceptional strength of an Si-F bond and the pKa of terminal alkynes vs other types, sp2 and sp3, C-H bonds.